# EKS cluster not reachable through kubectl during major scale up

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I have a cluster running on aws `EKS` with Kubernetes [Cluster Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler).
A few days ago I had a major scale up in which my cluster got to 50 nodes in a very short period of time. When that happened I tried to reach my cluster using `kubectl` and got no response for a few minutes.
I know that EKS `Cluster Autoscaler` provides HA for the `Control Plane` node by having 3 nodes in different `AZ` just for this kind of high load on the cluster.
So I'm trying to understand what may be the cause for this unresponsiveness of the `API server` (that resided in the `Control Plane`)?
Sorry of the lack of details but I'm just looking for a general direction what to look for before I do more research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`...Cluster Autoscaler provides HA for the Control Plane node by having 3 nodes in different AZ`

The control plane is [managed by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/disaster-recovery-resiliency.html) and serves with HA features *without* you install cluster-autoscaler:

> Amazon EKS runs and scales the Kubernetes control plane across
> multiple AWS Availability Zones to ensure high availability. Amazon
> EKS automatically scales control plane instances based on load,
> detects and replaces unhealthy control plane instances, and
> automatically patches the control plane.

`...trying to understand what may be the cause for this unresponsiveness of the API server (that resided in the Control Plane)?`

You should raise support case to AWS support if you encounter issue with the control plane, the control plane is **not** managed by the Cluster Autoscaler that you deployed.

The [Cluster Autoscaler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/autoscaling.html) automatically adjusts the number of *worker node* so that all pods can run. Likewise, when there is less pods running in the cluster, the component can also automate to terminate excessive worker node.

> The Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler automatically adjusts the number of
> nodes in your cluster when pods fail or are rescheduled onto other
> nodes. The Cluster Autoscaler is typically installed as a Deployment
> in your cluster.